# adding a child element to an existing element and putting the content of the parent node in the new child node

Tags: java, xml, dom

I am using Dom and Java to parse an XML document. In my XML, I have an element like:

```
<P>
All records required to be maintained pursuant to these regulations shall be maintained in accordance with Commission Regulation 1.31 (
<aref type="CFR">
17 CFR
<subref part="1" psec="" sect="31" title="17" tq="N">1.31</subref>
</aref>
) and shall be made available promptly upon request to representatives of the Commission and to representatives of applicable prudential regulators.
</P>
```

I need to put the content of this element into a new child element of `<p>` called `<text>` like this:

```
    <P>
<text> All records required to be maintained pursuant to these regulations shall be maintained in accordance with Commission Regulation 1.31 (<aref type="CFR">17 CFR <subref title="17" part="1" sect="31" psec="" tq="N">1.31</subref>
                            </aref>) and shall be made available promptly upon request to representatives of the Commission and to representatives of applicable prudential regulators.</text>
    </P>
```

I wrote a piece of code to do this trick (The idea is to iterate over all child elements and then move them one by one from under `<p>` to under `<text>`):

```
Element pTag = (Element) pTags.item(i); //This is to get the list of all pTags
Element textTag = doc.createElement("text");
int pTagChildIndex = 0;
NodeList pTagChildren = pTag.getChildNodes();
while(pTagChildIndex < pTagChildren.getLength()){
    textTag.appendChild(pTagChildren.item(pTagChildIndex));
    pTagChildIndex ++;
}
pTag.appendChild(textTag);
```

This code did not give me what I expected. It gave this:

```
<P>
<aref type="CFR">
17 CFR
<subref part="1" psec="" sect="31" title="17" tq="N">1.31</subref>
</aref>
<text>
All records required to be maintained pursuant to these regulations shall be maintained in accordance with Commission Regulation 1.31 () and shall be made available promptly upon request to representatives of the Commission and to representatives of applicable prudential regulators.
</text>
</P>
```

It seems that the code did not move all nodes. How can I move all the nodes from under `<p>` to under `<text>`?

Comment: You just want to wrap the contents of `<P>` inside a `<text>` block?

Comment: Yes. But I need the new <text> to be a child element of <p>. This means that <text> will be the only child of <p>.

Comment: I see. The problem is that you are using getLength(), and testing it during the while loop. When you mode the node from one place to another the length decreases, so you never get to process all the nodes. I'll post a solution based on your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initially your `<P>` element contains two text nodes and one element node. A total of three. But when you loop you remove an element from `<P>` and add it to `<text>`, reducing the total nodes to 2, and then you increment, and move the other text node, but now the length is 1 and you leave the loop without processing the element node.

The solution is to save the number of nodes copying `getLength()` to a variable that you can use in the loop, and always get the first element (`0`) until you have no more. You could change your code like this:

```
int elements = pTagChildren.getLength(); // save the number of nodes in a variable

while (pTagChildIndex < elements) { // loop using the variable
    textTag.appendChild(pTagChildren.item(0)); // always move the first element
    pTagChildIndex++;
}
```